# C++ cast to void

Tags: c++, casting, void

As I understand, C++ standard says that casting to void is correct only in case of function-style casting (*ISO/IEC 14882:2003, 5.2.3*).

But I can't find anything about *C-style* casting to void in *C++* standard.

Is behavior of program only implementation-defined in this case ?

Comment: When doing a C-style cast, `void` is like any other type, it's just that the value is ignored.

Comment: But where is this explanation in C++ standard?

Answer (score 4):

> As I understand, C++ standard says that casting to `void` is correct only in case of function-style casting

No, it can be done by `static_cast`, and therefore also by conversions using functional or cast notation.

> But I can't find anything about C-style casting to `void` in C++ standard.

It's defined for `static_cast` by [expr.static.cast], 5.2.9/6:

> Any expression can be explicitly converted to type *cv* `void`, in which case it becomes a discarded-value
>   expression.

[expr.cast], 5.4, describes how a C-style cast can use `static_cast`, so it's also valid for that style. [expr.type.conv], 5.2.3, described how functional style is equivalent to C-style, so it's also valid for that style.

<sub>(Note: section numbers refer to C++11 (ISO/IEC 14882:2011), not C++03 which you refer to, since that's the current version. Other versions may differ, but probably not much.)</sub>