# Cast instance to void?

Tags: c++, casting, void

This question is probably of little practial value, but I am just trying to understand what is going on here. I have a class:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo{
     operator void () { 
         std::cout << " to void called " << std::endl;
         return;
     }
};
```

Actually I wasnt sure if it is possible to convert a type to `void` (still not sure if it makes any sense, though), but after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115775/c-cast-to-void) I learned that it is possible at least via `static_cast`.

Now my question is....

```
void foo() {
    Foo f;
    //return f;                     // A // not allowed
    return static_cast<void>(f);    // B // OK
    return (void) f;                // C // OK
}
int main() {
    foo();
}
```

- Why is A not allowed? (if I would replace `void` with `int` it would obviously work)
- Why does neither B nor C call my conversion operator? (again, if I replaced `void` by `int` all three versions would call my `operator int`).
- I could accept that this is the way casting to `void` works, but then why am I allowed to define an `operator void` when it isnt used as I would expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "cast to void", however it is spelled, is a *discarded value expression*. It does not constitute a conversion, and therefore does not consider conversion functions.

C++ allows you to do lots of things that are pointless; it would be harder to *forbid* some special cases than to just leave the rules general.

Comment: in other words: "whatever cast to void does, it returns void, thus can be safely ignored, thus also no need to actualy perform the conversion", right?

Comment: @tobi303: More like, the cast to void is a discarded value expression, not a conversion.

Comment: hm ok, what I dont understand is if there is any way to call that operator directly. I also tried `f.void();` but that of course also makes no sense.

Comment: @tobi303 : sure : `f.operator void();`

Comment: @SanderDeDycker ah cool, I always thought coding is about creating something out of nothing, now I can even use my own way of turning something into nothing :). Seriously, thanks, didnt know about that syntax at all.